# Batman.js new app issue

Tags: javascript, batman.js

I've repeated steps from batman.js [readme](https://github.com/Shopify/batman#installation):

```
npm install -g batman
batman new mj
cd mj
batman server
```

And got this in Firebug trying to open localhost:1047

```
global is not defined

Mj.run();

localhost:1047 (line 52)
Mj.global is not a function

Mj.global(true);

mj.js (line 15)
Mj is undefined

Mj.run();
```

Did I missed something or should I open issue? Googling `batman.js global is not defined` gives no relevant results...

---

As it was pointed by user341180, problem is about node.js version. Have anybody patch for latest versions, or downgrade is the most wise way to deal with batman today?

---

Hmmm... In `README.md` it is stated that *you'll need to install node.js (0.4.x for now, 0.5.x support forthcoming)*, but `package.json` contains:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "~>0.6.0 || ~>0.7.0"
}
```

So, I'm confused. I suppose, `package.json` has more recent update, so batman should work with my node.js v0.6.19.

---

My current workaround is to define `root = @` befor `class Mj extends Batman.App` and replace `@global yes` with `root.Mj = @` inside one.

Comment: Just checking: you have done this first, right? "...install node.js (0.4.x for now, 0.5.x support forthcoming) and npm."

Comment: Sorry. Obviously you've installed npm, but is node.js installed right?

Comment: Oh, I did not pay attention to version remark. I have node.js v0.6.19, may be this is source of problem. Have anybody patch for this version or I'm obligated to downgrade?

Comment: @user341180: i've updated post about version confusion.

Comment: Why don't you write up your workaround as the answer? You figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a lot of changes between 0.9.0 and 0.10.0 and removing `global` was one of them.  Looks like the generator wasn't updated and is still generating 0.9.0 code.

I'm not actually sure how you're running the generator, it throws an error about calling `camelize` on an undefined object for me.

Anyway, this is definitely a 0.10.0 bug.

#### Added

The readme also looks like it wasn't updated from 0.9.0

#### More Followup

Looks like Shopify have [fixed this](https://github.com/Shopify/batman/issues/451) in edge now